# How to check all checkboxes usingheader checkbox in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin8

Ia m new to vVadin. I created one project with grid with two columns but i want to add one Textfield column and one checkbox column and check all checkboxes when click on header checkbox.

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Nicolaus Copernicus", 15),
            new Person("Galileo Galilei", 15),
            new Person("Johannes Kepler", 15));
     TextField txt =new TextField();
      CheckBox chk=new CheckBox();
        // Create a grid bound to the list
        Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>();
        grid.setItems(people);
        grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");
        grid.addColumn(Person::getAge).setCaption("Year of birth");
       grid.addColumn(Person-> new TextField());


        layout.addComponents(grid);


    setParent(layout);
```

can anyone suggest me.how to add those two columns

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Selection via check boxes works with the multi selection mode, see [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.selection.multi). On the same page you can read about `ComponentRenderer` which allows to put any component in a column. Note that this feature is available since Vaadin 8.1. released few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should help:

```
   paymentGrid.addComponentColumn(payment -> {
        CheckBox multiselected = new CheckBox();
        multiselected.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
            payment.setSelectedToMultiAction(event.getValue());
            if (event.getValue()) {
                selectedPayments.add(payment);
            } else {
                selectedPayments.remove(payment);
            }
            showButtons();
        });
        return multiselected;
    });
```